# Galois group of $f(x) = x^4-2$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$

Tags: galois-theory

I determined that splitting field of $f(x)$  is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]2, i)$ with degree $4$ . Therefore the Galois group has $4$ elements. Also $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$ which means that the Galois group is transitive. So Galois group is either $V_4$ or $C_4$ that are transitive subgroups of $S_4$. How to decide which one to pick?

Comment: $f(x)=(x^2-\sqrt2)(x^2+\sqrt2)$ is irreducible?

Comment: @Arthur ok, so it is reducible. Then it's not transitive and is $<(1,2), (3,4)>$?